# How to extend an orientdb embedded server to have my own servlets?

Tags: orientdb

I have created an orientdb embedded server standalone app to which I can query from console. However I need to extend the functionality to publish a page where multiple users can run queries and see (custom) svg visualizations. How can I do this?

I presume I need to create some html pages with servlets and also some orient db javascript libraries. But I am not sure how to connect all these.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Rao

Comment: It would be great to be able to "proxy" orient db HTTP protocol through a "normal" servlet to be used in standard J2EE container. Thus it could answer to request mapped under a specific path and avoid using its own socket. I'm working on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your pages under OrientDB server's www directory or also create a plugin that is a zip with pages and optionally Java classes. Unzip the studio file under plugins to see how is made.

Look also to how to [write plugins](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Extend-Server).

Answer (score 0):

I just found that required html files placed under the path: "[orientdb app path]/**src**/**site**" are accessible through http url. The bold ones are the folders which I created.

This path is looked upon in the OServerCommandGetStaticContent.java which in turn is configured in the config.xml for HTTP requests. I think if you wish you handle the http requests in your own java, you can mention that in the config.xml.

Thank you Luca for your pointer!

Rao